# Union of igraph objects loses attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I have two `igraph` objects, which have different color attributes.
Vertices `"A"` and `"B"` in first graph are colored red. 
Vertices `"AA"` and `"BB"` in second graph are colored green. 
After joining the two, the different colors are lost.

```
library(igraph)

graph.1= graph.data.frame(data.frame(start=c("a", "b"), end=c("A", "B")))
V(graph.1)[name%in% c("A", "B")]$color= "red"

graph.2= graph.data.frame(data.frame(start=c("a", "b"), end=c("AA", "BB")))
V(graph.2)[name%in% c("AA", "BB")]$color= "green"

graph= graph.union.by.name(graph.1, graph.2)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

How can I preserve the distinct colors when joining ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`igraph` doesn't loose the colors, it stores them in `$color_1` and `$color_2`. I think this is because in the general case there might be common vertices with different colors. What would you do then?

Try this:

```
V(graph)$color <- ifelse(is.na(V(graph)$color_1),
                         V(graph)$color_2,V(graph)$color_1)
plot(graph)
```

[image]

BTW: your code didn't run for me. I had to use:

```
graph <- graph.union(graph.1, graph.2, byname=T)
```

Comment: Hi Jihoward. Have you any idea how to do this for `n` igraph objects? (When you might have hundreds of graphs and literally can't write out the ifelse statement...) I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637321/combine-non-na-values-for-n-lists-r Thanks, C