# Combine non NA values for n Lists R

Tags: r, list, if-statement, nested, igraph

### A -  I have a list containing `igraph` graph objects:

```
goodgg

[[1]]
IGRAPH UN-- 3 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), color (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 89315--89316 89315--89928 89316--89928

[[2]]
IGRAPH UN-- 3 2 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), color (v/c), value (e/n), sourceID (e/n), targetID (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 106277--106278 106278--106279
```

### I can combine these into a single object using `[union][1]`:

```
combine = graph.union(goodgg[[1]], goodgg[[2]], byname=T)

combine
IGRAPH UN-- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: color_1 (v/c), color_2 (v/c), name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
```

### From this, I can extract particular attributes e.g. a `color`, which lines up with the order of the original objects (1 - 2):

```
as.list(get.vertex.attribute(combine))
$color_1
[1] "red"    "red"    "orange" NA       NA       NA      

$color_2
[1] NA    NA    NA    "red" "red" "red"

$name
[1] "89315"  "89316"  "89928"  "106277" "106278" "106279"
```

### How can I extract the non `NA` values in `$color_1` and `$color_2` and merge them into a new list when I have an arbitrary number of `color_n` entries? (E.g. I have n entries)?

To get:

```
[1] "red"    "red"    "orange" "red"    "red"    "red"
```

### What I tried (which does not work for `n` `color_` variables:

In this simple case I can do what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896087/union-of-igraph-objects-loses-attributes) answer did here:

```
V(combine)$color <- ifelse(is.na(get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_1), get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_2,get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_1)

get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color
[1] "red"    "red"    "orange" "red"    "red"    "red"
```

However, in reality my list could have `n` elements. How can I adjust this to account for `n` elements?

I considered using multiple nested IFELSE statements such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement-in-r) and [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-chain-ifelse-statements-in-r/) a la:

```
V(combine)$color <- ifelse(is.na(get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_1), ifelse(is.na(get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_2), ifelse(get.vertex.attribute(combine)$color_3)......))
```

This does not work for unknown `n` attributes and does not solve the issue of having an unknown number `n` of attributes to work with.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reduce` to "cumulatively" apply a function over a vector:

```
set.seed(125)

color_choices <- c("red", "orange", NA)

color_samples <- replicate(
  4,
  sample(color_choices, 5, replace = TRUE),
  simplify = FALSE
)
color_samples
# [[1]]
# [1] NA       "red"    "red"    "orange" NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA       "orange" "red"    "orange" "orange"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "red"    NA       "orange" "red"    "orange"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "orange" "orange" NA       NA       NA

Reduce(
  f = function(a, b) ifelse(is.na(a), b, a),
  x = color_samples
)
# [1] [1] "red"    "red"    "red"    "orange" "orange"
```

In this case, `Reduce` applied the function to the first and second elements, then to that result and the third element, then to that result and the fourth element.  If the list were longer, it would've kept going on that way.

Edit for your specific situation: save the list of attributes, find which have names like `color_n`, and then use the `Reduce` solution on those.

```
combine_attributes <- as.list(get.vertex.attribute(combine))
```

Because I don't have your data, let's just say `combine_attributes` looks like the `color_samples` created above with an extra element:

```
combine_attributes
# $color_1
# [1] NA       "red"    "red"    "orange" NA      
# 
# $color_2
# [1] NA       "orange" "red"    "orange" "orange"
# 
# $color_3
# [1] "red"    NA       "orange" "red"    "orange"
# 
# $color_4
# [1] "orange" "orange" NA       NA       NA      
# 
# $name
# [1] "89315"  "89316"  "89928"  "106277" "106278"

color_attributes <- grep(
  "^color_\\d+$",
  names(combine_attributes),
  value = TRUE
)

color_attributes
# [1] "color_1" "color_2" "color_3" "color_4"

Reduce(
  f = function(a, b) ifelse(is.na(a), b, a),
  x = combine_attributes[color_attributes]
)
# [1] "red"    "red"    "red"    "orange" "orange"
```

Comment: In my case, I don't have `a` and `b` predefined or allocated. Instead, I can only get the colours from `get.vertex.attribute(combine)` which gives the structure in the question.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your answer. I edited my question to try and be more clear on my needs. Many thanks for your answer. It's close to what I need.